# Do we really need an anatomically-correct tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The [anatomically-correct](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anatomically-correct) tag was recently created, which I noticed when all the questions in that series were edited to add it.  Do we need this tag?  The questions also have the appropriate other tags like [creature-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creature-design).  [anatomically-correct](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anatomically-correct) feels like a meta tag to me.  If exactly the same question were asked by somebody who didn't know about or intend to participate in the series, would the question get the tag?  What value does this tag add?

Comment: I feel like it's basically defined as the intersection of [tag:creature-design] and [tag:reality-check], so it seems to be like it's unnecessary.

Comment: I agree; it seems unnecessary.

Comment: I hold no opinion on this, It was suggest in the question; http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34221/anatomically-correct-medusa If you beleive it should be deleted the delete it

Comment: How do you filter all questions to get only those that have the two tags, which @2012rcampion mentioned, applied?

Comment: @Crissov [search `[creature-design] [reality-check]`](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creature-design+reality-check)

Comment: Given that the tag no longer exists, maybe accept the answer saying burninate it so we can move on in an anatomically incorrect fashion? :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As they would say on Stack Overflow: **BURNINATE IT!**

The tag is definitely, as 2012rcampion states, an intersection of creature-design and reality-check.

Furthermore, every question tagged with it already starts with "Anatomically correct"; to me, it almost feels like the tag is used solely to categorize questions starting with that title, which is totally wrong.