# What problems does this question have?

Tags: discussion

The question [Anatomically Correct Lamia](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/180683/anatomically-correct-lamia) has received numerous downvotes, but without any comments to say what problems there are to fix. What problems does this question have?

Answer (score 4):

The following is my point of view on why that question has been downvoted:

**First and general issue: The late ACS has degraded**

There have been already a couple of questions here addressing the point of misuse/abuse of the Anatomically Correct Series as an easy way to get reputation with questions of disputable quality. See [this](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7775/30492) and [this](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7842/30492). I guess many users now get hitches only at seeing an ACS question.

**Second and particular issue: some of your questions seems to be contributing to the first issue**

Most of your questions are along the line of

> Could [put arbitrary features or name here] evolve?

or

> What evolutionary pressure could lead to [put arbitrary features or name here]

This might give the impression that you are attempting to exploit a certain type of questions without putting too much effort in the question itself. I think you have been commented more than once that "given the right amount of events, anything could evolve" and yet you keep asking for another permutation of features.

Don't get me wrong, it's in your rights to ask yet another question along the ACS line, on the other hands it's in other users' right to downvote it because it is not useful.

Voting is exactly how the community expresses its opinion on each and every question and answer every user posts.

Answer (score 2):

I'd hazard the guess that it's because the question is a little unclear. You mention mythological origins, but then seem to be asking about some nebulous modern interpretation.

You might consider reading the Meta post on the [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series). This gives a number of suggestions on how to craft a good ACS query.

I'm going to hazard the further guess that your response has been downvoted because of its lack of structure and string-of-random-facts-cobbled-together nature. It's just random sentences & phrases strung together like mismatched beads.

We don't expect perfection in writing, but do appreciate when care is taken with the English language.